# How to pass two parameters to a method?

Tags: abap

I want to set 2 parameters to set_params, like this:

```
lo_newfal->set_params( ls_nbew-einri,  ls_nbew-falnr)
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
call method if_newfal->set_params
    exporting
      p_einri = me->ls_nbew-einri
      p_falnr = me->ls_nbew-falnr
```

This is how you can send 2 parameters in set_params.

Comment: Although correct I‘d consider this syntax outdated.

Comment: Could be, i'm sorry. I'm new to ABAP.

Comment: I apologise. I didn’t want to be rude: the CALL METHOD statement can be omitted but then one has to add brackets. The „me“ is superfluous as well. Additionally, in this case the EXPORTING is not necessary.

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not possible in ABAP. If you have more than one arguments, they have to be named explicitly:

```
lo_newfal->set_params( imp_param1 = ls_nbew-einri
                       imp_param2 = ls_nbew-falnr ).
```

This also means, you can call the arguments in any order:

```
lo_newfal->set_params( imp_param2 = ls_nbew-falnr
                       imp_param1 = ls_nbew-einri ).
```

However if there is one argument only in the method definition, it can be called without explicitly naming the argument:

```
lo_newfal->set_params( ls_nbew-einri ).
```

Comment: One addition to  Joszef's answer: you can also use the last format with one unnamed parameter if all but one parameter are optional.

Answer (score 3):

To quote the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapcall_method_static_short.htm):

> ```
> meth( a ).
> ```
>
> This is the short form of:
>
> ```
> meth( EXPORTING p = a ).
> ```
>
> The method meth can have the following parameters:
>
> - Either exactly one non-optional input parameter p and any number of optional input parameters
> - Or only optional input parameters from which p is defined as a preferred parameter using PREFERRED PARAMETER

So no, the shorthand method call where the target parameter is not specified can only be used when only one parameter can unambiguously be identified.
If multiple parameters are present, the *alternative 3* needs to be used where all the parameters are explicitly named:

> ```
> meth( p1 = a1 p2 = a2 ... ).
> ```
>
> This is the short form of:
>
> ```
> meth( EXPORTING p1 = a1 p2 = a2 ... ).
> ```

The same applies if IMPORTING or CHANGING parameters are present.

---

Compared to other languages, ABAP rather has named parameters than positional parameters. That has a clear advantage that one cannot by accident mix up the order of arguments (especially as ABAP does a lot of typecasting implicitly) and makes optional parameters way easier to handle.